# Why does File.Open() not open the file?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, streamwriter

I am implementing a Save File button in my VB.NET Windows Forms application.

I am attempting to encapsulate the normally expected behaviour of Save buttons in Windows applications. I.E: If a file was already selected then open the current file it, write to it and save it; else if there is no current file, or Save As was used, then show a `SaveFileDialog`, then open, write and save just the same.

I currently have coded the function below but I keep getting an exception:

> Cannot access a closed file

The file is created just fine, but is empty (It should contain `"Test string"`). I can't understand how the file is closed unless some kind of garbage collection is doing away with it somehow??

The current code:

```
Function SaveFile(ByVal Type As ProfileType, ByVal suggestedFileName As String, ByVal saveAs As Boolean, ByVal writeData As String) As Boolean
    Dim FileStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim FolderPath As String = Nothing
    Dim CancelSave As Boolean = False
    Dim SaveFileDialog As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()

    Try
        If Type = ProfileType.Product Then 'Select the initial directory path
            FolderPath = ProductPath
        Else
            FolderPath = ProfilePath
        End If

        If (FileName = String.Empty Or saveAs = True) Then 'If a file is not already selected launch a dialog to allow the user to select one
            With SaveFileDialog
                .Title = "Save"
                .AddExtension = True
                .CheckPathExists = True
                .CreatePrompt = False
                .DefaultExt = "xml"
                .Filter = "Xml Files (*.xml)|*.xml"
                .FilterIndex = 0
                .FileName = suggestedFileName
                .InitialDirectory = FolderPath
                If .ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    FullyQualfiedPathName = New String(SaveFileDialog.FileName) 'Save the path and name of the file
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(FullyQualfiedPathName)
                Else
                    CancelSave = True
                End If
                .Dispose()
            End With
        End If

        If (FileName <> String.Empty) Then 'Write the string to the file if the filewas correctly selected
            FileStream = File.Open(FullyQualfiedPathName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite) 'Open the file
            Using FileStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(FileStream) 'Create the stream writer
                FileStreamWriter.Write(writeData) 'Write the data
                FileStream.Close() 'Clse the file
            End Using
        ElseIf (CancelSave <> True) Then 'Only throw an exception if the user *didn't* cancel the SavefileDialog
            Throw New Exception("File stream was nothing", New IOException())
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & FullyQualfiedPathName)
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: You should close FileStreamWriter first and then FileStream. Not the other way around.

Comment: There is a [File.WriteAllText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you could use to efficiently replace the FileStream/FileStreamWriter code, with the bonus that it replaces a current file rather than splatting data at the start of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is that you should be putting your `File.Open` in a `Using` block:

```
Using fs = File.Open(fullyQualfiedPathName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Using writer As New StreamWriter(fs) 'Create the stream writer
        writer.Write(writeData) 'Write the data
        'fs.Close() <--- you do not need this line becuase the "Using" block will take care of this for you.
    End Using
End Using
```

I'm not sure if this will resolve your issue because I can't run your code, but the `Using` block will automatically take care of closing and cleaning up disposable instances like `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`, even if an exception is thrown.

By the way, you should use proper naming conventions (lower camel case) for local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have added the using but it did not solve the problem.
I thought I remembered MSDN informed me that pretty much all variables except parameter names should be upper camel case?? I'll see if I can find a reference

Comment: Here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: From your second link: "The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names...", "The camelCasing convention, used only for parameter names...". Though MSDN does immediately contradict itself at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240858(v=vs.60).aspx so each to their own I guess?

Comment: Your answer has actually solved the problem after I read @the_lotus comment, I removed the `.Close()`'s and got my `End Using` ducks in a row and its working now. Thanks!